# Are "air-waves" the same as "ether-waves"? I cannot find the meaning of the latter

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, literature

In a story I am reading, I would like to know what "ether-waves" mean:

> The odd thing really is that one should hear, but not see; that
> air-waves should bring the voice, yet ether-waves fail to bring the
> picture.”

Could it be meant to mean the same, just using another word to avoid repeating "air"?

Comment: What story, and written how long ago? _The ether_ is sometimes used as a poetic way of referring to the sky, or to the air as a medium for transmitting radio broadcasts.

Comment: @KateBunting Algernon Blackwood, I think it was written somewhere around 1910. http://algernonblackwood.org/Z-files/Entrance_Exit.pdf

Comment: Since the story is about something inexplicable, it's impossible to guess exactly what Blackwood meant. Presumably something like light waves.

Comment: @KateBunting Like many of today's pseudo-intellectual writers in the field of mysticism, he had taken buzz-words from contemporaneous science publications and mixed them up into a porridge of vaguely scientific-sounding semi-plausibility in order to add verisimilitude to a spooky tale of nonsense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are antiquated, "ether-waves" more than "air-waves". What is meant is "radio waves", or (more accurately) "electromagnetic radiation".

"Air waves" is still used colloquially to mean "radio communication" but it's understood as being a bit rhetorical or even poetic in feel, hence also used in advertising-speak.

*Nobody* has used "ether waves" for 100 years.

In the context you present, it would appear that the author doesn't have a clue what he is talking about. Bluntly: utter, utter blether.

Comment: Well the story was written more than 100 years ago, so I guess back then it was ok..?

Comment: @JohnV Heh! Algernon Blackwood. I rest my case. Second-rate writers have always dressed up their puerile woo-woo in pseudo-scientific poppycock, but around the turn of the 20th century was the heyday of such meaningless drivel.

Comment: But isn't Blackwood quite a recognized author? I vaguely remember H.P. Lovecraft himself praised him.

Comment: @JohnV Being "recognised" and being good are two completely different things. Lovecraft himself was an appallingly bad writer who happened to use some disturbingly vivid imagery -- and used the same technique over and over again. Similarly with Blackwood.

Comment: I think that "air waves" in this quote more likely refers to sound transmission; that is, actual pressure waves in the air. You are correct that "ether waves" is a reference to the now-obsolete [theory of the luminiferous aether](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aether_theories).